# Swift: drop down height bugs at first click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, drop-down-menu

I have this project where I use drop down menus. I use the following line to determine the height of the drop down list

```
self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
```

The first time I click the drop down, the height is all of, but afterwards it gets the right height. Do you have any idea why this is happening? You can see the problem and an example of my code by following the link below

https://github.com/Rawchris/drop-down-height

I hope you are able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution, but it is not beautiful. I have made it work by making the drop down expanding then retracting and then expanding again at the first click, just using the same code for expanding and retracting as before. If you know a better way to do it I will gladly hear it though :)